# What is the underlying pattern, or algorithm(s) used in these numbers?

Tags: data-mining, algorithms

I have 11 lottery tickets (used) and I have discovered that in each ticket, the 3rd digit's value is +1 of the value of the 6th digit. I have 11 tickets, each ticket is composed of 16 digits. Would someone (anyone) help me find the logic used here, in creating the other digits and their interrelation? I am a complete noob in data analysis, and any help would be greatly appreciated. For those who would like to know, I incidentally discovered the certain pattern, and made me realize these numbers are not totally random and if I could find the underlying pattern I'd be able to predict. The excel file is here [Excel file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=39010250377074241779)

Comment: [If you *do* want to post related questions at multiple SE sites](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133340/giving-100-to-whoever-can-identify-the-algorithms-behind-these-440-instances), please link them together.

Answer (score 6):

1. 11 instances of data is insufficient for discovering the behavior (even finding patterns) for such presumably complex systems. You need at least thousands of them.
2. These numbers are encoded versions of numbers generated by Serial Key Generation Algorithms, which in my experience are usually implemented by Python. So it's not at all strange that there may be a correlation between some digits of them. As it is necessary for the system to recognize its created numbers from the numbers created by other lotteries.
3. Even if there was a correlation or correlation between all the instances of lottery numbers, *correlation doesn't imply causation* and these patterns, if found any, couldn't really give any information about the key generation system itself.
4. If you are really serious about it. you could go to this page and enter your data as a sequence it would show you the pattern, if there is any:
   [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/)

Comment: That is a really good answer.  Just a formatting issue: could you please add newlines before points 3 and 4?  Currently they are lost in a single paragraph ...

Comment: @logc: Thank you. You can correct the formatting issues and such yourself using the edit button under the post.

Comment: No, I couldn't because edits have to be at least 6 characters long.  :)